# How can I get "related emails" on iPad, like in Mac Mail.app?

Tags: ipad, ios, mail.app, email

Lion's new mail.app update has a great feature for displaying emails where it shows "related" messages, ie both messages received and Sent are shown in the same conversation. Is there a way to get this on the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it can't be done in Mail under iOS 4.x. And it does not appear to be part of the initial improvements to Mail in iOS 5, according to news reports.